# Refresh webview on textviewclick?

Tags: android, webview, textview, android-webview

I have got this `TextView` with underneath it a `WebView`. It is working fine and all, but what I need is that when someone taps the textview that the underlying `WebView` gets refreshed.

Here's my .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:clickable="false">


<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/vu"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="60sp"
android:textColor="@color/text_color"
android:background="#212121"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my .java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Light.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.papery.hol.es");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);     
   }
}
```

Comment: setOnClick method for textView, and put your webview code inside it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I know what you mean, just not how to type it in actual code... could you edit my code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Light.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TextView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Every Time the textview clicked
            webViewWork();
        }
    });        

    // First Time
    webViewWork();

   }
}

void webViewWork(){
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.papery.hol.es");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your textview :

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Then in .java :

```
public void onClick(View v){
  switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.textView:
         webView.loadUrl("http://www.papery.hol.es"); // This line is just a representation
               break;
             default:
               break;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.